# Model Predictive Control with integral (end-of-horizon) constraints

Tags: reference-request, constraints, model-predictive-control

Let $\mathscr T = \{0,1, \ldots, T\}$ denote the entire time horizon, $x : \mathscr T \to [0,1]$ the state and $u : \mathscr T \to \mathbb [0,1]$ the control.
Consider the following problem:
\begin{align}
             & \max_{u}\sum_{t=0}^{T}{\ln(u(t))}\\
\text{s.t. } & x(t+1) = x(t) - u(t)\\
             & x(0) = 1\\
             & x(T) = \varepsilon > 0\\
             & u(t) \in [0, x(t)]~\forall t \in \mathscr T ​
\end{align}

I want to formulate the problem as an MPC problem.
Let $H < T$ denote the prediction horizon.
Further define a restricted state and control path by $x_t : [t, t+H] \to [0,1]$ and $u_t : [t, t+H] \to [0,1]$, respectively.
For all $t \in \{0,1,2,\ldots, T - H\}$ we consider the problem
\begin{align}
             & \max_{u_t}\sum_{s=t}^{t+H}{\ln(u(s))}\\
\text{s.t. } & x_t(s+1) = x_t(s) - u_t(s)\\
             & x_t(s) = x(t)\\
             & x(t+H) = ? > 0\\
             & u_t(s) \in [0, x_t(s)] ~ \forall s \in \{t,t+1,\ldots, t+H\} ​
\end{align}

As one can see I do not know how to incoporate the integral or end-of-horizon constraint $x(T) = \varepsilon$ into the subproblems.

- Is there a generic way to deal with end-of-horizon constraints in MPC problems?
- Or, what are common heuristics to incorporate them?

Answer (score 1):

I want to plan a trip to Barcelona and and should arrive there after 10 hours, and the initial plan I create must be followed. Now I only plan 8 hours, and I will create new plans every hour. My options are to either say I will arrive to Barcelona after 8 hours (and thus plan a faster travel), or add a penalty to the distance to Barcelona after 8 hours. You have the same options here. There is no definite answer.

Note that when you run this in closed-loop using an MPC strategy, you are not guaranteed (generally) to reach the terminal state in finite time, regardless if you plan the full horizon or the reduced horizon.